# capacity parameter must be greater than 0

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create an optimization experiment but when trying to run this error appears:

```
 root.queue1:
capacity parameter must be greater than 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.queue1:
capacity parameter must be greater than 0
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Queue.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.n(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentOptimization$m.m(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.j$c.run(Unknown Source)
```

the problem is that capacity of queue1 is greater than 0 by default, so i dont understand where i did a mistake =(

concept is i need to Implement an optimization experiment to determine the optimal number of fuel dispensers, at which the fueling profit during 10 days will be maximum.

model look like this:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Do show your `queue1` on Main. Do you accidentally change the capacity at runtime?

Comment: https://imgur.com/9jmgwnS.png

i cant edit the post (it just doesnt let me edit it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the capacity wrong. Simply write `queue_95` into the field, not `queue1.capacity=queue_95`.

Also, make sure that `queue_95` *never* is 0 or lower, obviously. (Whatever `queue_95` even is)